# MySQL Server - Got error -1 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-restore

I am currently trying to restore a MySQL table from the .ibd file.

I have been following the instructions on the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-tablespaces.html) on how to use DISCARD and IMPORT TABLESPACE to replace the .idb files. Discarding the tablespace returns no error and the file is deleted however IMPORTING the replacement .ibd file yields a "Got error -1 from storage engine" error.

There doesn't seem to be too much information about what exactly an error -1 is. Does anybody have any further insight as to why an import table space isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the exact procedure you are personally using, not the documentation you're referencing.  You're likely making a mistake.  I suspect it has to do with either the old table's files or data not being fully removed.

Comment: As Warner said, whilst it's mildly helpful to know what you're trying to do, it's *vital* to know what you're actually doing, and what results you're seeing as you do it.